# Unsolvable ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android-studio, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

Whilst doing a simple piece of code with a for loop I am encountering this error which is unsolvable as the index is not programmed to surpass the max index (5) of the titles array and yet I am getting the error claiming I am asking for index 5 on the 4th line no matter if I change the for(i) statement to a constant max of any other number (1,2,3, etc)

```
for (int i = 0; i < titles.length - 1; i++) {
            boolean doesContain = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < articles.size() - 1; i++) {
                if (articles.get(j).title == titles[i]) {
                    doesContain = true;
                }
            }

            if (!doesContain) {
                class_article newArticle = new class_article();
                newArticle.title = titles[i];
                newArticle.body = bodies[i];
                newArticle.category = categories[i];
                newArticle.date = new Date(Integer.valueOf(dateDays[i]), Integer.valueOf(dateMonths[i]), Integer.valueOf(dateYears[i]));
                newArticle.read = reads[i] == 1;
                newArticle.done = dones[i] == 1;

                articles.add(newArticle);
            }
        }
```

Any help on this infuriating issue would be appreciated.

[EDIT] One time I tried setting the max index for i to 1 and it loaded the app with 2 of the items being loaded except they were the same article, not article 1 and 2, but then when changing to a different fragment and then back again it resumed its strange, unexplainable error.

Comment: Have you tried running your code in a debugger and examing the actual state of the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < articles.size() - 1; i++) {
                if (articles.get(j).title == titles[i]) {
                    doesContain = true;
                }
            }
```

this piece of code is an infinite loop. you made a typo on the `i++` part, this should be `j++` (in the inner for-loop)

Comment: You wont be the first one to make this mistake :)